# How to make a photo to overlap site contents?

Tags: image, web, overlap

How can I make chat picture overlaps site contents.

http://www.foxpic.com/VOsuXV0B.png

the CSS code

```
    <style>
 .livezilla{ 
float:right;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

The live chat bottom code

```
<div class="livezilla" style="text-align:right;width:201px;"><!-- LiveZilla Chat Button Link Code (ALWAYS PLACE IN BODY ELEMENT) --><!-- LiveZilla Tracking Code (ALWAYS PLACE IN BODY ELEMENT) --><div id="livezilla_tracking" style="display:none"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement("script");script.async=true;script.type="text/javascript";var src = "http://yaradress.com/livezilla/server.php?a=81cbf&rqst=track&output=jcrpt&nse="+Math.random();setTimeout("script.src=src;document.getElementById('livezilla_tracking').appendChild(script)",1);</script><noscript><img src="http://yaradress.com/livezilla/server.php?a=81cbf&amp;rqst=track&amp;output=nojcrpt" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden;" alt=""></noscript><!-- http://www.LiveZilla.net Tracking Code --><a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://yaradress.com/livezilla/chat.php?a=a2e25&amp;epc=I2IwYWFhOA__','','width=590,height=760,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,menubar=no,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes'))" class="lz_cbl"><img src="http://yaradress.com/livezilla/image.php?a=00e3a&amp;id=1&amp;type=inlay" width="201" height="53" style="border:0px;" alt="LiveZilla Live Chat Software"></a><!-- http://www.LiveZilla.net Chat Button Link Code --><div style="margin-top:2px;"><a href="http://www.livezilla.net" target="_blank" title="LiveZilla  Live Chat" style="font-size:11px;color:#b7b7b7;text-decoration:none;font-family:verdana,arial,tahoma;"> </a></div></div>
```

The problem occurs because of  position: fixed; in CSS.

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Please some one help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

you have to add this code to CSS

```
z-index: 100;
```